# NFC and magnet interference in a concrete piece

Tags: electromagnetism, interference, nfc, magnet

Do you know if both NFC and a magnet would work correctly in this scenario?

I´m designing small pieces of concrete (imagine chess pieces) with three layers: magnet inside, NFC tag in the middle, and felt on the surface.

I would like a smartphone to be able to read the NFC and for the magnet to be used to attach it to a piece of metal.

[image]

Another option (taking into account the conductivity of the magnet) is to move the magnets to the sides:

[image]

Comment: I think, that the NFC works with magnetic field, so the permanent magnet will affect it.

Comment: I have read a lot about the subject and it seems that a stable magnetic field of the permanent magnet would not affect the NFC, since it works with a dynamic electromagnetic field. But of course, I'm not an expert on the subject ... :(

Comment: I just checked the conductiveness of the piece and is not conductive.

Comment: The magnet (being likely a conductor) will sap up eddy currents big time and this means that NFC may not work at all well.

Comment: So I suppose that if I put a electrically nonconductive barrier between the metal and the NFC tag, maybe it will work. I know that there are some special tags just to put them in metallic areas.

Comment: what is preventing you from running some tests?

Comment: @Andyaka The magnet is indeed a conductor, sintered NdFeB (the material neodymium magnets are made of) has a conductivity of something around 1% IACS, quite probably enough to cause problems.

Comment: @Kaixo No, the problem is not that there's electrical contact between them, the problem is that there's a conductor at all. If you were to move the magnet so that it's not directly on top of the NFC tag (or move the tag), even if you now have to use multiple magnets, you'll probably have better luck.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you for your answer. I just editted the question and I put another available option. In this case, the magnets will be more isolated to the NFC tag. What about this scenario? The felt will affect the NFC? Thanks!

Comment: This is an evolving question based not on firm answers but on guesses in comments. It looks like it will continue to evolve into a possible dead end as fewer and fewer people become involved. I'm flagging this for moderator intervention as it doesn't seem to fit to this site (my reason for flagging).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Comment: you appear to be drawing 2mm thick concrete features, they will not be durable. (well they might if it's not a cement-based concrete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFC does not work well near metal, space the tag as far away away from the metal as possible.  especially  do not place the tag between the metal and a metal magnet.

consider using bullet shaped tags in wells or embedding the tag more deeply when the concrete is cast.